# Visual Studio Code: How to change repo & see current repo

Tags: visual-studio-code, repository, repo

I'm pretty new into Visual Studio Code.
Does anyone know how I can find the current target repo.
I also asked my self how I can change the current repo.

Comment: in the terminal use `git remote -v` it will list the remote URLs

Comment: the repo is bound to a workspace, `.git` folder in workspace root folder, so change workspace to change repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, find the folder currently open in your workspace, simply hover over the filename of an open file to see the path to it.

If you mean, open up a new folder within the workspace, go to File > Open Folder > Then browse to desired folder.

Comment: By repository I don't mean my local workspace. Furthermore I mean something like Azure DevOps Repos.

Answer (score 0):

git remote -v will show you the repo you're currently on while git branch will list list your branches. then git switch will help you switch between branches